# Why spaces-separator between HTML <span> element is not already present when <span> elements are not on 1 line?

Tags: html, css, space, separator

I have written an little `HTML/CSS` code that display following image on `Chrome`

[image]

Why space-separations between (⯇ and ⯇) and between (┃ and ◆) are not there (see `yellow` unicode) ?

And why, when all `<span>` in `<span class='char'>` are in same line, space-separations are ALL visible (see `green` unicode) ?

The difference is only relative to how HTML code is written in file, nothing else ! The CSS code is totally identical (only background color was changed).

To facilitate the analyze of `yellow` case, I have put a third bloc with more colors.

The `HTML/CSS` code is following

```css
body
 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:20px;
 }

div.error span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: yellow;
 }

div.ok span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgreen;
 }

div.color > span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: orange;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.bar
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: cyan;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.triangle
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 }
```

```html
NO SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between (&#x2BC7; &#x2BC7;) and between (&#x2503;&#x25C6;)

<div class='error'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between all &lt;span class='char'&gt;

<div class='ok'>
    <span class='char'><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

NO SPACE-SEPARATOR with colors

<div class='color'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yellow one is physically wider than green which squizes out some space separators.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome ignores all of the inner and outer element whitespace characters in the HTML except if they are inside the text. All whitespace characters in between text is displayed as a singular space character but the actual value of the character is retained. This is for both elements that have the inline or the block display styles.

Every single element except for the last element of the body element, displays a space at the end when it is selected by using triple click or drag selection. This space is different based on the display style of the elements.

A block display element results in 2 CRLF characters appended to it when the text is copied while a inline display element only ever results in 1 CRLF. The whitespace characters are maintained between copy and paste but are limited to only one character.

while Firefox ignores outer element whitespace but has interesting results with inner element whitespace characters. All whitespace characters are converted to spaces with except for the starting character with a limit of one whitespace between each non-whitespace character. Only the last whitespace is shown and selected

**Inline Display**

There is always a space before and after the text that is copied regardless of what the elements contains. Every whitespace character is removed.

**Block Display**

Whitespace characters before the text are retained as-is and the ending whitespace character is converted to a space.

**So to answer your question, this is all based on how the browsers implement the display.**

**To fix it, you can remove all the spaces between your elements, in a way just minify your HTML.**

```css
body
 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:20px;
 }

div.error span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: yellow;
 }

div.ok span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgreen;
 }

div.color > span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: orange;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.bar
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: cyan;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.triangle
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 }
```

```html
NO SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between (&#x2BC7; &#x2BC7;) and between (&#x2503;&#x25C6;)

<div class='error'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span><span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span><span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between all &lt;span class='char'&gt;

<div class='ok'>
    <span class='char'><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span></span><span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span><span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='char'><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span></span><span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

NO SPACE-SEPARATOR with colors

<div class='color'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span><span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span><span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>
```

```css
body
 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:20px;
 }

div.error span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: yellow;
 }

div.ok span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgreen;
 }

div.color > span.char
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: orange;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.bar
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: cyan;
 }
div.color > span.char > span.triangle
 {
 font-size:40px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 }
```

```html
NO SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between (&#x2BC7; &#x2BC7;) and between (&#x2503;&#x25C6;)

<div class='error'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

SPACE-SEPARATOR<br> between all &lt;span class='char'&gt;

<div class='ok'>
    <span class='char'><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>

NO SPACE-SEPARATOR with colors

<div class='color'>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'>
        <span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span>
        <span class='bar'>&#x2503;</span>
    </span>
    <span class='char'>&#x25C6;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but you don't answer to main/first question. I have removed second question about different widths to remove ambiguity for future responder. Sorry for this inconvenience.